# Difference in Creating users in names.nsf and domino administrator?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I can create users from the `domino administrator` or `names.nsf`.What is the exact difference between these two things?

I created some users using domino administrator but i was unable to login into `names.nsf` using those created users.What is the reason for this?

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it should be posted on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this command `tell adminp process all` in the server console ? The Administration Process will take care all of your pending requests.`(creation in this case)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a timing issue with the view index update. There shouldn't be any difference as Domino Administrator updates directly in names.nsf. The ($Users) view needs to be updated in order for login to work.

Do you mean login using HTTP when you say "login into names.nsf"?